# How to merge two directories into same branch using git

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I want to merge two directories in the same branch.

I know git rules as if there is any required featured to add. I should have created a another another branch. and then i have to merge that branch into some another branch,

This is my current directory structure

```
App- 
    directory - 1
    directory - 2
```

How to merge these two directories into one. I have already seen many questions related, But nothing worked

Without creating new branch

**If there is another method to do this. Please suggest**

Comment: How merging two directories is related to Git? Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: I am using git for version control. Is it possible to merge two different directories in git ..?

Comment: Merging directories has nothing to do with Git. Merge them and commit your changes.

Comment: Merge them but how..? Both of them in the same repository.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that all your changes have been committed and that your branch with both directories is called `both-directories`.

This approach will loose all your git commit history for `directory - 2` and squash them into one commit. If you want to keep that commit history you have to modify step 1-5 for every commit before continuing with step 6.

1. Copy the files from `directory - 2` to a folder outside of git. Lets call that folder `outside-directory-2`
2. Find the commit that introduced `directory - 2` and start a new branch from its ancestor. Call this branch something like `directory2`.
3. Check out the branch `directory2`.
4. Copy all contents from `outside-directory-2` to your `directory - 1` folder.
5. Commit these changes to the `directory2` branch.
6. Check out the branch `both-directories`.
7. Merge the branch `directory2`
8. delete the folder `directory - 2` and commit these changes.
9. Now your branch `both-directories` contains all changes from `directory - 1` and `directory - 2`.